# Setting paper sizes with new commands

Tags: geometry

I made a style file `chil.sty` residing in some library path with the following page sizes.

```
\RequirePackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\aluminpg}
  {\geometry{paperwidth=13cm,paperheight=21cm}}

\newcommand{\scandpg}
  {\geometry{paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=21cm}}

\newcommand{\ironpg}
  {\geometry{paperwidth=26cm,paperheight=21cm}}
```

My question is twofold -

1. How to use the package (at some directory) in a document
2. Would there be a requirement to specify `\documentclass` without setting the papersize, knowing that it will be set by the geometry package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, typically questions should be one question per question but as they are similar it may be okay. For your first question, you could put `\RequirePackage{geometry}` in your `.sty` file so the end user doesn't need to load it, I haven't published a `.sty` class/package just yet but I am assuming that they should be self-contained i.e. load the packages that are needed for the class/package to function

Comment: every latex document needs `\documentclass` setting the page size is a minor part of its function

Comment: What do you mean by 'the style file resides in *some* path'? Do you want it to be accessible from every .tex document? Then you need to put it somewhere your TeX distro can find it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What does one specify for `\documentclass` when one wants to have some non-standard specific geometry.  Does one always use the `geometry` package, or can one specify the exact page size using `\documentclass` ?

Comment: Correct, I want my documents to use a library that I coded up in some directory structure.  My document would need to call library commands to set the pre-defined page size.

Comment: it depends on the class you are using, article class only has a few fixed sizes. a4, letterpaper. other classes may have more but this is just a tiny part of what a class specifies, all the section headings, figure layout, page styles enumerated lists,.... are specified by the document class, changing a couple of lengths for height and width of the page is not something strange

Comment: Whatever the available classes may be, the document page size would be defined by the parameters defined by `\aluminpg` or other predefined sizes in my library like `\scandpg` and `\ironpg`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What would you suggest ? Declare a document class with a class specific page layout, then change it using geometry ? If one does not specify the page size in `\documentclass`, will the document take some default page size ?

Comment: I can't suggest anything really as you have not given much of a clue as to your use case.  The latex default textheight and width are `\textheight=.5\maxdimen
\textwidth=\textheight` so you really need to specify them in your document class.  You don't need to use `geometry` unless you want to, look how `article` class defines `a4paper` and `letterpaper` options (just a couple of lines for each)

Comment: also in your question you say you are making a package (`.sty`) file,  but in comments you are asking about designing a class (`.cls`) file?

Comment: I am doing a `.sty` file but was referring to your comments about the `\documentclass`.  I though that to change the page size to a custom one, I had to use geometry.  It is what most people have suggested.

Comment: You don't have to use `geometry`. However, if you're using a standard class like `article`, `geometry` makes it easier to alter the layout. For example, it will automatically calculate missing dimensions or allow you to specify dimensions in more intuitive ways. However, it shouldn't usually be used with classes which offer their own interface for this, except in special-use cases (e.g. the Koma-script classes, Memoir, Beamer etc.).

Comment: If you want your `.sty` file to be found, you need to put it in a specific place. Which place depends on the distribution of TeX you are using. The file should also declare itself as a package in order for it to behave properly e.g. `\ProvidesPackage{chil}[2023/09/20 v0.1 Custom page sizes]`.

Comment: I cannot see how developers often complicate things for the sake of producing confusions.  For instance, you specified that geometry should not be used with classes which offer their own interface.  How would know all these details.  Why don't developers of classes simply include the possibility for users to set default page sizes ?  It is a small step and yet it seems they cannot get themselves to complete.